# Getting errors when launching Elastic Beanstalk instance in AWS for Django app

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Python 3.9.5 for my Django app and I am trying to deploy it on AWS in Elastic Beanstalk. The platform I chose was AWS Linux 2 with Python 3.8.  When I try to do an `eb create`, I get this stacktrace error:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
        objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
        self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 129, in _compile
        raise CompileError(msg)
    distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/setup.py", line 154, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 299, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 306, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 541, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 578, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/command/sdist.py", line 226, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_python()
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 107, in _add_defaults_python
        build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 37, in finalize_options
        orig.build_py.finalize_options(self)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/command/build_py.py", line 43, in finalize_options
        self.set_undefined_options('build',
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 287, in set_undefined_options
        src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/setup.py", line 143, in finalize_options
        self.distribution.ext_modules = get_ext_modules()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/setup.py", line 128, in get_ext_modules
        import cld2
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/cld2/__init__.py", line 187, in <module>
        _full_cld2 = _full_ffi.verify('#include <binding_decls.h>',
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/.eggs/cffi-1.14.5-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/api.py", line 468, in verify
        lib = self.verifier.load_library()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/.eggs/cffi-1.14.5-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/verifier.py", line 104, in load_library
        self._compile_module()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/.eggs/cffi-1.14.5-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/verifier.py", line 201, in _compile_module
        outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile(tmpdir, self.get_extension())
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/.eggs/cffi-1.14.5-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 22, in compile
        outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose, debug)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v7gtd0uf/cld2-cffi_20eacbc571034a60bc5a47d71b1737a7/.eggs/cffi-1.14.5-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 58, in _build
        raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
    cffi.VerificationError: CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/6d/044789e730141bcda2a7368836f714684a7d13bd44a2a33b387cb31b4335/cld2-cffi-0.1.4.tar.gz#sha256=3a29948364ed1e426c5bf542832eee208b1c70c0ad512b1a99bec0e6486f6c67 (from https://pypi.org/simple/cld2-cffi/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cld2-cffi==0.1.4 (from versions: 0.1.1, 0.1.3, 0.1.4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cld2-cffi==0.1.4
 

2021/06/28 05:05:10.028254 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/06/28 05:05:10.028356 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1624856710,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1624856710,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2021/06/28 05:05:10.028538 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2021/06/28 05:09:53.602699 [INFO] Starting...
2021/06/28 05:09:53.602746 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2021/06/28 05:09:53.602761 [INFO] reading event message file
2021/06/28 05:09:53.602865 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2021/06/28 05:09:53.602925 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2021/06/28 05:09:53.668640 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:465435786833:stack/awseb-e-53i6aevdmm-stack/176ff4a0-d7ce-11eb-a76f-02cd38bb34df -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-west-1
2021/06/28 05:09:53.981851 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:465435786833:stack/awseb-e-53i6aevdmm-stack/176ff4a0-d7ce-11eb-a76f-02cd38bb34df -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-west-1
2021/06/28 05:09:54.274593 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2021/06/28 05:09:54.274608 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2021/06/28 05:09:54.274612 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2021/06/28 05:09:54.274662 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2021/06/28 05:09:54.274666 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2021/06/28 05:09:54.274907 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log
```

It appears that some library in my Python code isn't being read or found correctly, but I have no idea how to debug it.  Does anybody know how to approach this problem?

Comment: Missing some C/C++ library. What are the dependencies of your application?

Comment: There's a list of libraries I bundled up in requirements.txt.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes. Something must require external libraries there which need to be complined.